# JQuery: two functions zoom and swap but zoom keep original image

Tags: jquery, html

I have two Jquery functions one to show a zoom / detail of the image and another two display multiple images from thumbnails.  They both work, until you swap an image, then the new image displays but the old image is still in the zoom function.  I guess I need to also update the new zoom function but I'm not sure how to go about this.  how do you force this reload or refresh of the function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#image').addimagezoom() 
        magnifiersize: [300,300] 
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("li.tmb-all a").click(function() {
        var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
        $("#image").attr('src', mainImage);
        return false;       
    });
    })

</script>
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="main_image">
  <img alt="available in 10 colors" id="image" itemprop="image" src="/products/440/large/custom-woven-1.jpg" width="400" />
</div>
    </div>
      <!-- no need for thumnails unless there is more then one image -->
<ul id="product-thumbnails" class="thumbnails" data-hook>
  <li class="tmb-all" id="tmb-440"><a href="/spree/products/440/large/custom-woven-1.jpg"><img alt="Custom-woven-wristbands-1" src="/products/440/mini/custom-woven-1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li class="tmb-all" id="tmb-442"><a href="/spree/products/442/large/custom-woven-2.jpg"><img alt="Custom-woven-wristbands-2" src="/products/442/mini/custom-woven-2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li class="tmb-all" id="tmb-439"><a href="/spree/products/439/large/custom-woven-3.JPG"><img alt="Custom-woven-wristbands-3" src="/products/439/mini/custom-woven-3.JPG" /></a></li>
  <li class="tmb-all" id="tmb-441"><a href="/spree/products/441/large/custom-woven-4.jpg"><img alt="Custom-woven-wristbands-4" src="/products/441/mini/custom-woven-4.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding the magnify code inside the click:

```
$('#image').addimagezoom() 
    magnifiersize: [300,300] 
});


$("li.tmb-all a").click(function() {
    var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
    $("#image").attr('src', mainImage);
    $('#image').addimagezoom() 
      magnifiersize: [300,300] 
    });
    return false;       
});
```

Plugins typically have a way to destroy themselves too which if it did you'd maybe be able to do something like `$('#image').destroy().addimagezoom() 
        magnifiersize: [300,300] 
    });`  assuming it actually supports that (check the docs).

Comment: excellent, all I had to do was just cal the function inside the function but thanks for the idea!